# Magento 2.4: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The XML in file Element 'event': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( observer )

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4

i am getting  below error in magento 2.4 and it is working fine in magento 2.3.
how can i resolve this one?
Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The XML in file "/var/www/html/magento240/app/code/PPPL/PhonePe/etc/frontend/events.xml" is invalid: Element 'event': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( observer ). Line: 4 Verify the XML and try again. in /var/www/html/magento240/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:156 Stack trace: #0

Please find the below code

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd"><event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <!-- Do nothing -->
</event></config>
```

Comment: Share that file codes /var/www/html/magento240/app/code/PPPL/PhonePe/etc/frontend/events.xml"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <!-- Do nothing -->
    </event>
</config>

Comment: Share the code in questions with proper format.